# Area enclosed by the curve $\lfloor x + y\rfloor + \lfloor x - y\rfloor = 5$

Tags: analytic-geometry, area

> What is the area enclosed by the curve $$\lfloor x + y\rfloor + \lfloor x - y\rfloor = 5$$ $$x\ge y, \forall x, y \ge 0$$
>
> $\lfloor x\rfloor$ stands for the Greatest Integer Function.

I think that the curve will start from $\left(\cfrac{5}{2},\cfrac{5}{2}\right)$ and then be a straight line parallel to the $y$ axis till $\left(\cfrac{7}{2},\cfrac{5}{2}\right)$ (not including this last point). But then I am finding it difficult to manipulate it further.

Comment: It may help to identify the symmetries of this figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given equation is:
$$ \lfloor x+y \rfloor + \lfloor x-y \rfloor = 5 $$
Let $t_1 = x+y \text{ and } t_2 = x-y$.
We can begin by observing that LHS is the sum of two non-negative integers. So the ordered pair $(t_1, t_2)$ can possibly be $(5,0),\;(4,1),\;(3,2)$ and so on. Consider $(t_1, t_2)=(5,0)$. For this pair, we can write the inequalities:
$$ 5\le x+y < 6 \\ 0 \le x-y < 1$$
The intersection of these inequalities gives a part of the total graph. Similarly we may write all inequalities for all pairs, and draw the graph.

[image: Graph]

Now it is easy to observe the pattern and use the inequalities to find the complete graph. With non-negativity restrictions on $x$ and $y$, the graph of the solution is the three diamond (tilted square) regions whose centres lie on $x=3$.

Thus the area of the graph is $3/2 \text{ sq. units}$.

<sup>Image credit: [Desmos Graphing Calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator)</sup>

Comment: Could we assume $x+y=p$ and $x-y=q$ as the new coordinate axis's and then the question converts into finding the area enclosed by $[p]+[q]=5$ . This gives 6 units.

Answer (score 2):

Blue tiles:
$$
\lfloor{x + y}\rfloor + \lfloor{x - y}\rfloor = 5
$$
Gray triangle
$$
 y > 0, \quad x \le y
$$
Find the area of the blue tiles within the gray triangle.

[image: regions]

The black dots are the vertices of the first square:

$$
\left( \begin{array}{c}
  3 \\ 0
\end{array} \right), \quad 
%
\left( \begin{array}{c}
  3.5 \\ 0.5
\end{array} \right), \quad 
%
\left( \begin{array}{c}
  3 \\ 1
\end{array} \right), \quad 
%
\left( \begin{array}{c}
  2.5 \\ 0.5
\end{array} \right)
%
$$
The side length for each square is $s =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Therefore each square has area $A=s^{2} = \frac{1}{2}.$ There are three squares within the second region. Therefore the total area is 
$$A_{total} = 3 A = \frac{3}{2}$$